# where do default arguments "live"?

Tags: c++

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
```

```
// this one does not work
// error: use of deleted function ‘O::O(const O&)’
class O
{
    std::fstream f;
};
```

```
// works
class O
{
    O(std::fstream fs) : f(fs) {}
    std::fstream &f;

public:
    O() : O(std::fstream()) {}
};
```

```
// also works
class O
{
    std::fstream &f;

public:
    O(std::fstream fs = std::fstream()) : f(fs) {}
};
```

```
int main(void)
{
    O my_o;
    std::vector<O> objs{my_o};
    return 0;
}
```

In this example the first version doesn't compile because the class O "owns" the fstream.
The other two versions do compile.

In the working examples who "owns" the fstream? is it as if it were defined within main?

Is this a reasonable way to deal with this problem? It feels hacky to me but I don't want my users to have to bother with allocating the fstream or even knowing that it exists.

Comment: `std::fstream` can't be copied, thus `O` can't copy its member `f`, thus the copy constructor is deleted.

Comment: @273K sorry. had some formatting issues while copying it over apparently. should be fixed now.

Comment: You bind the references to temporaries in the both last O snippets, get dangling references. This is UB.

Comment: @273K ah ok. that makes sense I guess. So instead I should implement the copy constructor?

Comment: The #2 and #3 versions own a **reference**, but do not manage the lifespan of the object.  Default values of parameters "live" at the *call site*, and are passed in as the argument.  (The code looks very susceptible to *dangling reference* problem.)

Comment: @stewpend0us "compiles" doesn't mean "works" all versions are invalid: https://godbolt.org/z/jTa8q7aan in fact version which you claimed to be wrong is closes to be correct: https://godbolt.org/z/q7hen76dT

Comment: The question title doesn't match the question...

Comment: A better question title might be "How can I write a class containing a non-copyable field?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of your solutions compile.  None of them do anything sensible.

The first one doesn't compile because you try to copy a `std::fstream` object when you put it into a `vector`.

The remaining ones engage in a mixture of dangling references and nonsensible behavior.

If you have a class with a reference and you store it in a `std::vector`, **it will not behave sensibly**.  Vectors expect objects that are at least semi-regular; references do not follow semi-regular value semantics.

As a concrete example of why non-semi-regular values are non-sensible in a vector will expect creating an object and moving it over another object does something reasonable.  Your code does not.

```
// works
class O
{
    O(std::fstream fs) : f(fs) {}
    std::fstream &f;

public:
    O() : O(std::fstream()) {}
};
```

this code compiles but is otherwise useless.

On default creation of an `O` object, you create a `std::fstream` object.  You then capture a reference to this object.  Then it immediately goes out of scope and you have a dangling reference.

Your copy/move constructor makes a new reference to this dangling object.

Your copy/move assignment operator attempts to assign to this dangling object, which causes undefined behavior.  The best thing you can hope for is a crash.

Your other solution "works" similarly.

I'm uncertain if a copy-constrution of a dangling reference object is UB or not, but regardless many other simple operations are UB, such as:

```
O my_o;
std::vector<O> bob{my_o};
bob.resize(2); // UB
```

None of these solutions work.  I do not know what you are trying to do.

When writing a C++ program, you are responsible for the lifetime of resources you use.  An `fstream` represents a file handle, which is a resource.  Either your code has to understand and control the lifespan of the `fstream`, or your user has to understand and control the lifespan of the `fstream`.

As I don't know what your code is doing with the `fstream`, I cannot advise further.  Feel free to describe the real underlying problem **in another question** and ask it on stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

When you write this:

```
class O
{
    std::fstream f;
};
```

You get 6 special member functions "for free", sometimes talked about as the "Rule of Zero".

This includes the copy constructor. However, you can't copy an `fstream`. How would a copy of a stream work? The `fstream` therefore deletes its own copy constructor, which causes the default-generated copy constructor of your `O` class to be deleted as well, hence the error:

```
error: use of deleted function ‘O::O(const O&)’
```

When you change `O` to hold a reference instead, its copy constructor means that you might have a few `O` objects referring to the same `fstream`, which might be OK, but then you need to watch out for the `fstream`'s lifetime.

You can delete your own class's copy constructor explicitly, but you will still need to allow a default-generated default constructor:

```
class O
{
    std::fstream f;
public:
    O(const O&) = delete;
    O() = default;
};
```

You could then make a `vector` with one (or more) `O`'s in it:

```
std::vector<O> objs(1);
```

You might need to give further consideration to the other member functions (move constructors and assignment, and copy assignment, and maybe the destructor).